# What does a subscript number after a question title mean on the flag summary page?

Tags: discussion, flags, user-interface

I recently flagged a comment on English.SE.  Later on I went to check on my flag, which is still active.  I clicked on the number of helpful flags on my profile, which brought me to the [flag summary page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/28567):

[image: (screen shot)]

There's a subscript 3 after the question title.  What does it mean?

Comment: Is the downvote because I forgot to include information like what I searched for before asking?  Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That count is the number of answers that there are on the question.